# Ambiguous use of append?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to make a basic calculator using Swift but I can't figure out how to add numbers to the top when they are pressed. I'm trying to append the number to the string each time the button is pushed, but I am getting the error "Ambiguous use of append". What is wrong with my code that is causing this error and how can it be fixed so that it function?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var oneButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UILabel!




    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func onePressed(sender: AnyObject) {

        textField.text?.append("1")

    }

}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Note that the convention when dealing with collections in Swift is: `append` adds a single element to the end of the collection, `extend` adds the contents of another collection.  With strings, that means `append` adds single characters, whereas `extend` adds other strings (or other collections or sequences of characters such as an array).

In the case of append, `String` has two functions for appending.  One takes a `Character`, and one takes a `UnicodeScalar`.  Both are called append though.

You can see them if you get the completion popup on a string variable:

[image: image of completion options for String.append]

You need to tell Swift which one you want:

```
textField.text?.append(“1” as Character)
```

or

```
textField.text?.append(“1” as UnicodeScalar)
```

This ambiguity is caused by the multiple overloads of literal conversion when there is only one character between the `""`.  When you write `"a"` it can result in one of several types being produced – a `String`, a `Character`, a `UnicodeScalar` or maybe a custom type that has a `StringLiteralConvertible` implementation (like say a type representing a URL).  `String` is ruled out (`append` doesn’t take one) but that still leaves the other two.

If on the other hand you had a `Character` variable already, there would be no need for disambiguation:

```
let c: Character = "a"
textField.text?.append(c) // no ambiguity
```

Swift decides from the context (i.e. what the type of the arguments of potential matching function calls might be).  The other solutions suggest the `+` concatenation operator, or `.extend()`.  `+=` would also work.  These aren’t ambiguous because they are not overloaded – they only take a `String` (or in the case of `extend`, another collection of characters, which is what a `String` is), and therefore Swift can pick the conversion from literal to `String` without any help.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Was unaware of the "as" syntax in Swift.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `+` for concatenating strings.

Use like:

```
@IBAction func onePressed(sender: AnyObject)
{
    if let txt = textField?.text
    {
        textField?.text = txt + "1"
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't I define **let txt = textField.text** with all the button outlets at the top? Being able to do that would be much more efficient.

Comment: @Physics137: I didn't understand what you are asking, can you explain a little bit ?

Comment: If I could put the **let txt = textField.text** at the top of the code, and not inside of the function, I could just say **textField?.text = txt + "number"** without having to type **let txt = textField?.text** repeatedly

Comment: @Physics137: Because when you initialize the class the textField will be nil. Also the value of textField is changing when you press the button again and again. So it's better to initialize the value inside the IBAction method

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are using `append` when you mean `extend`. Write this, and all will be well:

```
 textField.text?.extend("1")
```

Comment: Who says they means `extend`?  The intention might be to append a character.  Just because extend is unambiguous doesn’t mean that’s the right solution, just hiding the problem...

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity Much as I respect your work, this will have to be one of those cases where you say what you say and I say what I say.

Answer (score 0):

**Appending a String to a String**

Although the accepted answer is technically correct and a very good one, it's seems (my assumption) all the OP was trying to do is append a string to a string and not append a UnicodeScalar or Character literal to the string.

If that was your intention and I assume most users would want to do something similar, use `.appendContentsOf(other: String)`.

```
textfield.text?.appendContentsOf("1")
```

Also, `.extend()` has been deprecated is no longer available.